# Из string в таймер - как?

Tags: c#, winforms

Получаю некую переменную `string` - она выводится в элементе `panel` - в ней может храниться текст:

- только что
- 10 секунд назад
- 39 мин. назад
- 5 ч. 45 мин. назад
- вчера 23:03
- 2 дня назад
- 15 ноября 2017 г.

Как мне всю эту красоту превратить в таймер ?

Что бы был не просто статичный текст, а каждую секунду/минуту/час/день - значения бы менялись.

Comment: а может в том участке откуда приходит переменная есть более простой формат описания времени события? по идее, общий алгоритм такой, если в лоб идти: 1. распарсить этот текст, находим значение когда произошло событие(наиболее творческий участок) 2. инициализируем таймер с этим значением и текущим временем

Comment: @Akubik эти строки получаю при парсинге с сайтов - другого вида у них нет. 1 ваш вариант - означает преобразовать эти строки в DataTime и уже дальше мудрить ?

Comment: @Vipz Обычно на сайтах при наведение на подобный текст выскакивает PopUp окно с полой датой, которую запарсить куда легче, чем это. А парсить такое, ну фиг знает...

Comment: а что за сайт для примера? или сам парсер сайтов не вариант переписать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - ничего там не вылезает. Тупо находится в HTML и с помощью JS тикает. А данная информация мне необходима.

Comment: @Akubik - данную информацию я просто вытаскиваю из HTML строки.
Сверху конкретный пример, что ещё надо  ? Есть переменная string - как сделать таймер ? Их преобразовывать в DataTime и дальше куралесить ?

Comment: _и с помощью JS тикает_ - значит, время есть в JS. Вот оттуда его и нужно вытаскивать. Что нелегко, да. Или парсить вручную все приведённые в вопросе варианты - что тоже проблематично.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написать простенький парсер.

```
Сейчас: 11/30/2017 2:15:00 PM
30.11.2017 14:15:00 <= только что
30.11.2017 14:14:50 <= 10 секунд назад
30.11.2017 13:36:00 <= 39 мин. назад
30.11.2017 08:30:00 <= 5 ч. 45 мин. назад
29.11.2017 23:03:00 <= вчера 23:03
28.11.2017 14:15:00 <= 2 дня назад
15.11.2017 00:00:00 <= 15 ноября 2017 г.


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    args = new[]
    {
        "только что",
        "10 секунд назад",
        "39 мин. назад",
        "5 ч. 45 мин. назад",
        "вчера 23:03",
        "2 дня назад",
        "15 ноября 2017 г."
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Сейчас: {0}", DateTime.Now);
    foreach (String timeStr in args)
    {
        DateTime time = Parse(timeStr);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} <= {1}", time.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"), timeStr);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static DateTime Parse(String timeStr)
{
    if (timeStr == "только что")
        return DateTime.Now;

    Int32 curLength = timeStr.Length;

    // Убираем слово "вчера", если оно присутствует - парсим время
    timeStr = timeStr.Replace("вчера ", String.Empty);
    Int32 newLength = timeStr.Length;
    if (newLength != curLength)
    {
        TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.Parse(timeStr);
        DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
        return yesterday + time;
    }

    // Убираем слово "назад", если оно присутствует - это разница во времени
    timeStr = timeStr.Replace(" назад", String.Empty);
    newLength = timeStr.Length;
    if (newLength != curLength)
    {
        String[] formats = {@"ss\ \с\е\к\у\н\д", @"mm\ \м\и\н\.", @"h\ \ч\.\ mm\ \м\и\н\.", @"d\ \д\н\я"};
        TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.ParseExact(timeStr, formats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        return DateTime.Now - result;
    }
    else
    {

        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU");
        String[] formats = {"dd MMMM yyyy г."};
        DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(timeStr, formats, culture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Разумеется форматы и культуру нужно скэшировать, а не создавать каждый раз заново. Если производительность критична (миллиарды дат), то вместо реализации на основе Replace можешь написать собственную посимвольную парсилку. Но, скорее всего, такой задачи перед тобой не стоит.

P.S. У тебя наверняка будут и другие форматы. Например `s секунд` вместо `ss секунд`. Допиши их самостоятельно. В `TimeSpan` не забудь экранировать все символы помимо форматных, включая пробелы.